# How do I run java program with multiple classes from cmd?

Tags: java, cmd

At the moment I am looking for another way to run my Java program from command line, other than adding it to a JAR file. My program has the following number of classes:

The name of the program file - MyProgram
Main class - Server1
second class - Client Handler
Package name - Items
3rd class - User1
4th class - User2

The main class and client handler alongside the package will have to run first in order for user 1 & user 2 to run, because they are client classes and are dependent on the main class.

Comment: Are you having an issue with your approach? Is your build directory on your classpath?

Answer (score 38):

```
javac *.java // compliles all java files in the dir

java MyClass // runs the particular file
```

If one class is dependent on another class that hasn't been compiled yet, the program won't run. So you should compile all files before trying to run the program dependent on other files.

If your files are packaged, then something like this

```
javac com.mypackage/.*java

java com.mypackage.MyClass
```

Comment: To be honest, I do this all the time, even when only compiling 1 file because *.java is shorter than file.java

Comment: My three hours were wasted before I chanced upon the above. I wrote the different class files in different files and put it all in the same directory and compiled. Compile success. Program runs.

Answer (score 12):

you must ensure that you add the location of your .class file to your classpath. So, if its in the current folder then add . to your classpath. Note that the windows classpath separator is a semi-colon ie ;

```
javac -cp . PackageName/*.java
java -cp . PackageName/ClassName_Having_main
```

**Example**. Suppose you have the following

- Package Named: com.test
- Class Name: Hello (Having main)
- Java file is located inside "src/com/test/Hello.java"

then, from outside directory:

```
$ cd src
$ javac -cp . com/test/*.java
$ java -cp . com/test/Hello
```

Note that you can add -d to specify output directory of your class files whenever compiling

```
$ javac -d output_directory -cp . com/test/Hello
```

In windows the same thing will be working too, I already tried

Check out [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html) from Oracle official site

Answer (score 8):

Once you compile your code, you then run this from the top level:

```
java -cp . com.myprogram.MyProgram
```

That order thing you describe doesn't matter. They all get compiled together, and `MyProgram` will reference `Server1`, etc.

Comment: So what does the -cp do? I never saw it used with the java command until now, and when I tried it, it worked!

Answer (score 4):

It may be more then you want to tackle right now but you might want to consider a build system like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/index.html).  To start try out; [How do I make my first Maven project?](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_make_my_first_Maven_project)

You can use it to predefine the build order and if you want have it create a jar for you (or not).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you will just need to open multiple command prompts and compile and run them in the order you need them to run.  Let me know if I misunderstood question.

Answer (score 1):

TO EXECUTE TWO JAVA PROGRAMS WHICH DEPENDS TO EACH OTHER.
(for example:two files Complex.java and Solution.java, where Soultion.java depends upon Complex.java.
So Complex.java should be compiled first and then the class file of Complex must be linked with Solution.java and then Solution.class must be executed for Output.)
REFER THE IMAGE WITH SYNTAX.

STEP 1:

### COMPILE Complex.java

compiling Complex.java

syntax-
javac -d [path_where_class_File_build] [path_of_the_file\filename.java]

(Solution.java and Complex.java are Linked. ie-Solution.java calls Complex.java)

STEP 2:

### COMPILE Solution.java

compiling Solution.java with linking Complex.class
with linking Complex.class(above created in step 1)

syntax-
javac -d [path_where_class_File_build] -cp [path_of_the_first_class_created] [path_of_the_file\filename.java]]

STEP 3:

### EXECUTE THE Solution.class

java -cp [path_of_second_class_created] [class_Name]

(created in Step 3)
[image]